# Error in forEach Spark Scala : value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get avg of ratings of all json objects in a file. I loaded the file and converted to data frame but getting error while parsing for avg. 
Sample Request :

```
{
        "country": "France",
        "customerId": "France001",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "2.3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "AVBS34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "SeriousPie",
                "placeId": "VBSs34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "Canada",
                "rating": "4.3",
                "famousRest": "TimHortons",
                "placeId": "AVBv4d"

            }        
    ]
}
```

so for this json, US avg rating will be  (2.3 + 3.3)/2  = 2.8

```
{
        "country": "Egypt",
        "customerId": "Egypt009",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "1.3",
                "famousRest": "McDonald",
                "placeId": "Dedcf3"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "EagleNest",
                "placeId": "CDfet3"

            },


}

{
        "country": "Canada",
        "customerId": "Canada012",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "UK",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "XSdce2"

            },


    ]
}
```

for this avg for us= (3.3 +1.3)/2 = 2.3

so over all, the average rating will be :  (2.8 + 2.3)/2 = 2.55    (only two requests have 'US' in their visited list)

My schema :

```
root
|-- country: string(nullable=true)
|-- customerId:string(nullable=true)
|-- visited: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |   |-- placeId: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- placeName: string (nullable = true) 
|    |   |-- famousRest: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- rating: string (nullable = true)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("temp.txt")
df.show()
```

When doing :

```
val app = df.select("strategies"); app.registerTempTable("app"); app.printSchema(); app.show()
app.foreach({
  t =>  t.select("placeName", "rating").where(t("placeName") == "US")
}).show()

I am getting : 
<console>:31: error: value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row t => t.select("placeName", "rating").where(t("placeName") == "US") ^
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `app` is a `Dataframe` (your code example isn't comprehensible... you create a `df` variable and query an `app` variable), you shouldn't call `foreach` in order to select from it:

```
app.select("placeName", "rating").where(t("placeName") == "US")
```

`foreach` would call a function on each record (of type `Row`). That is useful mostly for invoking some side-effect (e.g. print to console / send to external service etc.). Mostly, you wouldn't use it for selecting / transforming Dataframes.

**UPDATE**:

As for the original question of how to calculate the average of US-only visits:

```
// explode to make a record out of each "visited" Array item, 
// taking only "placeName" and "rating" columns
val exploded: DataFrame = df.explode(df("visited")) {
  case Row(visits: Seq[Row]) => 
    visits.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("placeName"), r.getAs[String]("rating")))
}

// make some order: rename columns named _1, _2 (since we used a tuple),
// and cast ratings to Double:
val ratings: DataFrame = exploded
  .withColumnRenamed("_1", "placeName")
  .withColumn("rating", exploded("_2").cast(DoubleType))
  .select("placeName", "rating")

ratings.printSchema()
ratings.show()
/* prints:
root
 |-- placeName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rating: double (nullable = true)

+---------+------+
|placeName|rating|
+---------+------+
|       US|   1.3|
|       US|   3.3|
|       UK|   3.3|
+---------+------+
 */

// now filter US only and get average rating:
val avg = ratings
  .filter(ratings("placeName") === "US")
  .select(mean("rating"))

avg.show()
/* prints:
 +-----------+
 |avg(rating)|
 +-----------+
 |        2.3|
 +-----------+
  */
```

Comment: val app = df.select("strategies");
        app.registerTempTable("app");
        app.printSchema();
        app.show()

Comment: the app gives the table consists of list of visited (which is a array of struct) thats why used for each to look through the list

Comment: Can you point me to correct direction to find the avg of all placeName = US

Comment: I tired this :df.registerTempTable("people")
   sqlContext.sql("select avg(expResults.rank) from people LATERAL VIEW explode(visited)people AS expResults where expResults.placeName = 'US' ").collect().foreach(println) but getting error

Comment: You should update the question with all this information (the code creating `app`, and the code that you've tried) - I'll try answering this but updating the question will help others do so too

Comment: Thank you for ur detailed explanation :) Can I add filter here ? To use rating of US to calc avg only if it  is > 3.0 ??  case Row(visits: Seq[Row]) => 
    visits.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("placeName"), r.getAs[String]("rating")))

Comment: isn't the average supposed to be 2.5 ?

Comment: @Newbiee I ran it on a subset of the data, it's 2.55 for all data... and yes - you can add the filter either within the explode function or at the end - after / when filtering US only

Comment: I am getting this error : non-variable type argument org.apache.spark.sql.Row in type pattern Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116109/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-newbiee).